# How can I center a Pin in Mapsui

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mapsui

New to Mapsui.

How can I center a Pin in the MapView and how can I set the zoom level in order to show only the desired portion of the map around the Pin?

Comment: https://mapsui.com/api/Mapsui.Viewport.html

Comment: Dealing with other things I didn't gave a look to `Viewport` until now. How can I use it? I have created a new map following this example: https://mapsui.com/documentation/getting-started-xamarin-forms.html Where exactly can I set `Viewport`?